# Issue: overflow: scroll makes all the divs with the same class scroll

Tags: html, css, web

I am using overflow: scroll property in a CSS class and in case, one div has an overflow the scroll works but the problem is that all the other divs with the same class are being scrolled. How can I fix that?

Comment: Poor explanation of problem. Show what you have tried and what problem you're getting.

Comment: use a class for the `div` you want to have a scroll, I assume you've added scroll for the `div` element. To help you better it is always good to share the code what you have achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Give a custom className like as `.over-flow-scroll` to your element and just add css to this class, it's help you in future if you need again any `overflow:scroll` feature.

Comment: This did not fix the problem

Comment: Please send an example or part of your code you are trying

Answer (score 0):

Give the `<div>` you want to have `overflow: scroll;` to and give it a seperate id which won't effect the other divs.

**Working Example:** https://codepen.io/Ajjarindahouse/pen/BajZroV